# Generate random point inside a polyhedron

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

I would like to know if there are *known* algorithms for generating a random point(say following a probability distribution *P*) inside an arbitrary polyhedron(possibly non-convex and may contain holes)?

I find approaches for 2D case like the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8420395/985166) but none in the case of polyhedrons(3D). Whether extending this approach for 2D is the only way, in which case that *random* point will still be forced to be on the surface of a triangle of a tetrahedron in the 3D triangulation of the given polyhedron?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you polytope is convex, [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9854/uniformly-sampling-from-convex-polytopes) should work. Otherwise you can always do rejection sampling: Sample a point from the bounding box, check whether it's inside the polygon. That gets really slow for high dimensions and "unboxy" polytopes though, because the bounding box potentially has a huge volume compared to the region you're interested in.

Comment: I am using polyhedrons to represent machine components which are three dimensional and non-convex. BTW, what do you mean by "unboxy" polytopes?

Comment: If the polytope looks like a hypercube, sampling by using the bounding hypercube works ok. If it is very different from a cube, the runtime explodes.

Comment: Will this approach for convex polytope work if the polytope has holes...I mean will that random point always lie inside polytope but not in hole?

Comment: If it has holes, it's not convex. You will have to read the papers to see whether the methods can be adapted and perhaps ask a new question.

Comment: I have edited this question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

To implement adrianN's rejection sampling method, you will need a function to determine if a point is inside your polyhedron. This not-completely-trivial problem is discussed in my book *[Computational Geometry in C](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html)*, and there is [code available](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/ftp.html).

---

[image: Fig7.10]

Comment: Will it also work for polyhedrons with holes?...Actually, in my problem, I get this polyhedron after symmetric difference between 2 input polyhedrons, which often creates holes.

Comment: @Pranav: Yes, because it just counts ray crossings.